# MySQL - Search each field for specific character

Tags: mysql, perl, search

I have a mySQL database set up and a "contact" table with multiple fields for different contact information.  It is baffling to me but I guess for some reason clients don't always put their email information in the "email" field when adding to the DB.  Is there a quick and easy way to search every field of every record for an '@' symbol?  If not, can someone help me whip up a perl line or script to leave only the strings with '@' in a txt file?  I plan on looking into perl for data massaging among other things but I just don't have the time right now.  Thanks!

-Austin

Comment: `mysqldump` or `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` and `grep` might get you what you need, if you're just curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will iterate over all rows and save results in file when some column contains `@`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use DBI;

my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:mysql:db_name','user','pass')
  or die "Connection Error: $DBI::errstr\n";

my $sql = "select * from table";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";

open my $fh, ">", "output.txt" or die $!;

while (my $r = $sth->fetchrow_hashref) {
  $r->{$_} =~ /@/ and print $fh "Found '@' in column $_ of row:", Dumper $r
    for keys %$r;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually ended up just doing it the long way with a couple queries and then excel work but I'll use this in the future.  I'll definitely have to do it again.

Answer (score 0):

For each column you can do

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 LIKE '%@%' OR col2 LIKE '%@%' OR ....
```

Just make sure you omit the email column and you'll get just the rows that may have emails in the wrong column.

Since you now included the information that this is a table with many columns, and this is an impediment to the approach described, you can use mysql's data dictionary to generate a list of column names for your table.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='your_database' AND TABLE_NAME='your_table' AND COLUMN_NAME != 'email';
```

With the column names it should be easy enough to get use an editor that supports macros and use that to construct the full list of columns for your OR clause in a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks, I would do that but there are 160 columns (this was built way before my time) and I haven't been deemed worthy enough to make permanent changes to the website (I'm still the new kid on the block).

Comment: Maybe it's easier to just mysqldump the database and work with tools like grep or text-processing perl?

Comment: Or you could do what gview proposed for a single column and then [loop through columns](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+loop+through+columns)